# Azure web site deployment throwing. Mislead between DataBaseFirst and CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, ef-code-first, dbcontext

I'm stuck with this "dreadful" error message trying to deploy an MVC web site on Azure :

> Code generated using the T4 templates for Database First and Model
>   First development may not work correctly if used in Code First mode.
>   To continue using Database First or Model First ensure that the Entity
>   Framework connection string is specified in the config file of
>   executing application. To use these classes, that were generated from
>   Database First or Model First, with Code First add any additional
>   configuration using attributes or the DbModelBuilder API and then
>   remove the code that throws this exception.

DataBase First Workflow was used from scratch (adding *ADO.Net Entity Data Model* element and following wizzard connecting to an Azure SQL Server DB). So I can't figure out why it's besetting me with Code First. Using EF 6.0 with T4 templates. Generated DbContext looks like this :

```
    public partial class MyAppEntities : DbContext
    {
        public MyAppEntities()
            : base("name=MyAppEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<AType> AType { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<BType> BType { get; set; }
        // etc.
    }
```

Connection string looks like this. Copied both in DAL project and StartUp project web config :

```
<add name="MyAppEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MyAppModel.csdl|res://*/MyAppModel.ssdl|res://*/MyAppModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ndkkyxvogj.database.windows.net;initial catalog=DbName;persist security info=True;user id=myuserid;password=Pa$$word;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

App runs without any problem on local machine.

Deploying process on Azure follow these steps.

- Create (custom creation) web site on Azure and give db credentials
- Download publish profile from Azure dash board
- In VS click Publish from start up project and set following parameters :
- -> Profile : Import downloaded profile
- -> Connection : Connection well set and validates
- -> Settings : **Not sure at all what is awaited here !!!** I tryed both connection settings : With suggested connection strings and with EDMX connection string. like this :

  metadata=res://*/MyAppModel.csdl|res://*/MyAppModel.ssdl|res://*/MyAppModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=ndkkyxvogj.database.windows.net;initial catalog=MyDb;persist security info=True;user id=databaseuser;password=Pa$$word;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"

Tryed to comment OnModelCreating(). Didn't work.
Also tryed to comment throw on UnintentionalCodeFirstException(). Didn't work either.

Despite research on other SO Q & A, couldn't find any reliable solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it ...

Actually, falling on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840326/entity-framework-work-locally-but-not-on-azure/15858768) and [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740625/azure-publish-database-first-connection-string-not-working), it appears that it is Azure misleading between the connection string names both given the same in Azure Sql Server and the Azure Web Site.

It has nothing to do with a whatsoever bad EF implementation between code first/model first or db first ...

So I gave connection string name a new one in the web App config, Context Class constructor, and in the azure web sites connection string name parameters ... And it worked.

It was a real pain figuring this out ...